# How do I show different color for cancel in iOS alert?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a possible way to add a different color to cancel for iOS alert using Swift?

My code is as follows:

```
@objc func showAlert(){
    let codeNotReceivedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Code not received?", message: "Resend security code (it can take up to a minute to arrive)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    codeNotReceivedAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8465872407, blue: 0.7545004487, alpha: 1))
    codeNotReceivedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Resend", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        
    }))
    codeNotReceivedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        
    }))
    
    present(codeNotReceivedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When I have run your code then I found an alert with the following details:-**

[image]

**1st Solution:-**

**If you want to change the cancel button color with red color(change cancel button style as destructive) then you should use the following code:-**

```
 @objc func showAlert(){
    let codeNotReceivedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Code not received?", message: "Resend security code (it can take up to a minute to arrive)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    codeNotReceivedAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8465872407, blue: 0.7545004487, alpha: 1))
    codeNotReceivedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    }))

    codeNotReceivedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Resend", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    }))

    present(codeNotReceivedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Then the output should be like this:-**

[image]

=================================================================

**2nd Solution:-**

**And if you want to another/custom color for the cancel button and also don't want to change cancel button style then You can use the following code:-**

```
  @objc func showAlert(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Code not received?", message: "Resend security code (it can take up to a minute to arrive)", preferredStyle: .alert)
         alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8465872407, blue: 0.7545004487, alpha: 1))

           // Create Resend button
           let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Resend", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

               // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
               print("Ok button tapped");

           }
           alertController.addAction(OKAction)

           // Create Cancel button
           let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
               print("Cancel button tapped");
           }
         // **Change Cancel title color according to your requirements**

             cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.yellow, forKey: "titleTextColor")

           alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

           // Present Dialog message
           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

**For example, I have used cancel button as yellow color the output like this:-**

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried your solution but it did 2 things. 1. It removed bold from the text. 2. It added ... instead of completing the sentence . Here's the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/tj0fmm any solution?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your feedback, I have submitted two solutions, I don't know which of them you have used. But according to your query, I think you have used the first one, where I have changed the cancel button style from .cancel to .destructive style that's why the cancel button does not look bold. 

You can use the second solution where I have used a yellow color for the cancel button text color.  In the second solution, there is an option to change the text color according to your requirement.

Comment: Sir this works perfectly. Last thing. I noticed the cancel is in bold and resend is regular. Why is that? And how do I make resend bold too?

Comment: For the second solution Resend and cancel both are the same. But you can change text style as well as text color similar to the cancel button code. just put resend button outlets.

Comment: working for me.....

Answer (score 0):

No.

Apple likely does not want to allow different things like this.
They want to keep consistency between apps, so they often constrain UI elements' capabilities.

You can make your own alert that supports colors, but there is probably a reason Apple did not add it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if you mean to employ `UIAlertController` to do this. `UIAlertController` can only be used with three kind of styles of `UIAlertAction`:

```
extension UIAlertAction {
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public enum Style : Int {
        case `default` = 0
        case cancel = 1
        case destructive = 2
    }
}
```

Here is the code and screenshot to demonstrate:

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Do you mean to discard the changes?",
        message: "Going back may cause data lose",
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )
        
    let saveAndLeave = UIAlertAction(title: "Save before leaving", style: .default) { (_) in
        print("")
    }
    alert.addAction(saveAndLeave)
        
    let leaveDirectly = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirmed", style: .destructive) { (_) in
        print("")
    }
    alert.addAction(leaveDirectly)
        
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Let me think", style: .cancel) { (_) in
        print("")
    }
    alert.addAction(cancel)
        
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: screenshot]